# Set a breakpoint on all methods of C++ class in visual studio professional 2019 edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I am not able to set a breakpoint on all the methods at a time using mentioned path

Debug --> New Breakpont --> function Breakpoint.

[image: New Function Breakpoint]

Answer (score 0):

> Set a breakpoint on all methods of C++ class in visual studio
>   professional 2019 edition

**I am afraid that you cannot get what you want in VS2019.** And this issue is still a persistent, general problem which was reflected by several community members. See [one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/414490/set-a-breakpoint-on-all-methods-of-c-class-vs2017.html), [two](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/407582/new-function-breakpoint-not-working-for-classname.html), [three](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102154/set-a-breakpoint-on-all-methods-of-c-class.html) and so on.

In the latest VS version, such as `VS2017`,`VS2019`, it still does not work in my side but in the old version such as **VS2012** which I have tested and works as expected.

**VS2012**:

[image]

**To** help you solve this issue, I reported this issue on our DC Forum. See [this link here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/982182/cannot-use-classname-in-function-breakpoint-to-set.html). You can vote it and add any detailed comment to supplement this issue. And any community member who is interested in this issue will vote for you and all of them will cause the related staff's high attention.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Hi ,thank you , till know i am waiting for the the solution.

Comment: Is it available for download ?